# Reference for Function-Valued Random Variables?

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, oc.optimization-and-control, random-functions

**Question:** Are there any good references for facts about function-valued random variables? In particular for facts like the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ be a random variable with values in $X$, and $F$ a random variable with  values in $C(X, \mathbb R)$. Define the function $\overline F: X \to \mathbb R$ by $\overline F(x) = \mathbb E[F(x)]$. If $Y$ and $F$ are independent then $\mathbb E [F(Y)] = \mathbb E [\overline F(Y)] $.

**Background:**

Consider the online optimisation setup where we have a fixed set $X$ and each turn select an action $x_n \in X$. We get some real-valued reward $r_n(x_n)$ and some feedback and use this to decide the action on the next turn.

I am interested in when the rewards are noisy realisations of some fixed function. That means $r_n(x_n) = r(x_n) + \epsilon_n(x_n)$ for some fixed (but unknown) function $r: X \to \mathbb R$ and i.i.d functions $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,\ldots : X \to \mathbb R$ such that each $\mathbb E[\epsilon_n (x)] =0$.

The only difficulty defining function-valued random variables seems to be deciding what a measurable set of functions is. In order to prove anything useful we will need the evaluation function $(f,x) \mapsto f(x)$ to be measurable. The first roadblock comes from Auman's *Borel Structures for Function Spaces* which says there is no good notion of measurable sets in the set of all measurable functions.

Fortunately we can do better if we assume more structure. If $X$ has a topology and we restrict attention to continuous functions, then we can give the function space our favourite topology and the induced  Borel Structure. It turns out if $X$ is sufficiently nice then the Borel structures induced by the uniform and pointwise topologies are the same. From this point we just assume as usual there is a measure space $(\Omega,P)$ and measurable functions $\epsilon_n: \Omega \to C(X, \mathbb R)$ that satisfy the usual independence relations.

In this setting the goal is to bound $\sum_{i=1}^N r(x_i) $ on expectation. Naturally this leads to considering $\mathbb  E[\epsilon_n(x_n)]$. By construction $x_n$ is a function of $\epsilon_1,\ldots, \epsilon_{n-1}$ so is independent of $\epsilon_n$. From this I can for example prove using standard (but lengthy) measure theory arguments that $\mathbb E [\epsilon_n(x_n)] =\mathbb E [\overline {\epsilon_n}(x_n)] $ where we define $\overline {\epsilon_n}(x) = \mathbb E[\epsilon_n(x)]$. For the proof observe when $\epsilon_n, x_n$ are simple the equality is obvious. Use Arzelà–Ascoli to see  $\epsilon_n$ is a limit of simple random variables. The same is true for $x_n$. Then use dominated convergence.

However this is an awful lot of work and doesn't have any fundamentally new ideas from the standard undergraduate measure theory course. I wonder are there any good references for facts like the above. So far I can find very little about function-valued random variable as all!

Answer (score 3):

Brownian motion, i.e. Wiener measure, is a good source of ideas and examples here.

For instance if $W_t$ is 1-dimensional standard Brownian motion at time $t$ and $$P(\forall x\,F(x)=x^2)=1$$ and $Y=W_1$ then $F$ and $Y$ are independent but $$E(F(Y))=1\ne E(F(E(Y)))=E(F(0))=0.$$
(Actually here we just need that $W_1$ is a standard normal random variable.)

Comment: Sorry there was an error in the original question that makes the "fact" false from examples like yours. Do you have any ideas about the corrected question?

Comment: I guess this is all for now